# Graph API save login information

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I am using the Graph API for Facebook on my iPhone application. The problem is, I don't want the user to have to re enter their email address each time they want to login to integrate Facebook with my app. Is there a way to save and auto fill the login information using the Graph API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Graph API, there is no need for you to store the credentials, more than that, you should ***NOT*** store the credentials. As explained in [the API dedicated help page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) the authentication process is handled by a secure token.

Meaning that if the user is already authenticated on Facebook using another application, it might be ( based on authentication process used ) already authenticated within your app.
You might check the token validity by using the ***isSessionValid*** method from the Facebook class.

Have a look to the [iOS Facebook SSO](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/ios_sso/) link, it explains everything you need.